# Http Request - external url request ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I couldn't found how to do a get http request, so I hope you guys can help me.

The idea is to receive the json data from a external url (for example, https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=twitterapi), and display to the user in the html.

I'm using ember 2.4, and I couldn't found how to do this.

Could you please help me understand which files I need to change?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please show what you've already done to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you loading JQuery as well?

Comment: On the http://emberjs.com/ page scroll down to "LOADING DATA FROM A SERVER" or see this twiddle https://ember-twiddle.com/53536c504a4323ebabe1

Answer (score 0):

Use [ic-ajax](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-ic-ajax)

Then u can use this code:

```
ajax({
  url: 'linktoapi',
  type: 'get'
}).then((data)=>{
  //do something with data
})
```